# Ruby 2.3 load method doesn't return classes loaded anymore - Returns boolean instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activesupport

I am migrating a project from Ruby 1.8.7 to Ruby 2.3 and rails from 2 to 4.

I have this code which was working in 1.8.7

```
class_list = []
original_mechanism = ActiveSupport::Dependencies.mechanism
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.mechanism = :load 
  begin
    class_list += load("/tmp/abc.rb")
  rescue Exception => e
    debug e.backtrace
  end
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.mechanism = original_mechanism
```

my sample file abc.rb

```
class Abc
  def ...
end
class Def
...
end
```

In Ruby 1.8.7 class_list is **[Abc,Def]**

In Ruby 2.3 class_list is **[true]** - (I had to change the line to 'class_list << load("/tmp/abc.rb")' to make it give this output )

Any of you know how to make it return the old way? All I want is the ClassNames of the classes loaded at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not Ruby. Ruby's `load` always returned `true`, both in 1.8.7 and 2.3.1. However, there's ActiveSupport `load` that uses `load_dependency` (http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.0/ActiveSupport/Dependencies/Loadable/load_dependency) which does return new constants defined in the file.

Can you try to use `load_dependency` instead of `load` here?